# Azure CosmosDB Bad Request 400 with blank reason and substatus 0

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are using CosmosDB with SQL API and Serverless.

We are getting strange BadRequest CosmosException's without a reason text and a substatus 0 text.

We enabled AllowBulkExecution to load some data quickly running 64 tasks in parallel.

When ever this happens I am able to find the item and run it alone and I am able to call `UpsertItemAsync` on it. but whenever I try and do it in parallel, it fails almost immediately.

Nothing have changed in the data. Its the same `/id` value and partition key.

I've excluded everything from the index include path, and using `/id` as the partition key.

The diagnostic data do not show any obvious difference between a successful call and a failed one.

Have anyone experienced anything like this before and know what the root cause is?

Comment: Can you run the same code without AllowBulkExecution? I have found that Bulk does not include the error message because of the compression protocol. HTTP 400 means normally one of these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-bad-request

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I found out the errors are transient. If i do a retry loop and add in some jitter I'm able to retry the failed 400 request in 2-4 attempts. The errors don't seem to appear when i run the code without Bulk execution. Its almost like the 400 should have been 429's. Being able to retry them means its not one of the listen errors such as invalid id or partition key etc.